# box-shadow being cut off

Tags: css

While using CSS3's `box-shadow` I am having an issue I do not usually have.

The box shadow usually just bleeds over the div edges, but not on this one.

`box-shadow` that is being cut off on the top and right hand side..

Heres the css I'm using for box-shadow:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #555;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #555;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #555;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If `box-shadow` is being cut-off, make sure `overflow:visible` is set on any div(s) your element is contained in.

Comment: I took out the example site link in the original post, so I am leaving this explanation for people having this issue in the future.

Comment: How can I get the drop shadow displayed though if overflow:hidden is needed? For example a floating dashboard grid that needs to scroll if it's content overflows

Comment: @DavidMays You'll want to add another containing div with enough margin/padding to show your entire dropdown shadow in this new container with overflow scrolling.

Comment: And if you want the scrolling element to be inside the shadowed element you're out of luck.

Comment: needing a more general solution, it's not always possible to modify overflow of parent containers

Answer (score 61):

The problem is your center-main div is cropping off the edge of the shadow. Set `overflow:visible` on this and you should see it.

Comment: Thank you, I thought this was the issue but I didn't see this one. You're amazing.

Comment: Or you can remove `overflow:auto;`

Answer (score 15):

use padding + negative margin like:

```
.img {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: -10px;
}
```

Comment: 2019 Oct.  I was having this problem with a drop-shadow on IOS Chrome.  Intermittently.  This solved it! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have run into this problem multiple times with IE, and the best solution I've found is to use a transparent outline around the div. This seems to prevent IE from clipping the box shadow, as it does even in cases where Gecko and Webkit don't. One great thing about using outline to fix this problem is that it doesn't affect the position of the div.

For example, I had a div with which I had used **position: absolute** and **bottom: -30px** to put it in a certain place relative to its parent div. IE, and only IE, was cutting off the top and bottom of the box shadow. Adding this outline fixed it, without changing the position.

```
outline: 10px solid transparent;
```

Comment: This works perfectly when you're using `box-shadow` as a pseudo responsive border.

Answer (score 0):

you can set this style img tag for show shadow-box correctly

```
.img{
  margin:20px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #555;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #555;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #555;
 }
```

Comment: This would of course, change the positioning of the image as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
.img{
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #555);
}
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the same issue on my local project by setting the image to have the following css property:

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this issue. In these cases I add `position: relative` and a `z-index` to the box shadow container.

Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/742obmes/) for a visual.