# Box-shadow still cutting off with overflow-y set to visible

Tags: css, overflow, box-shadow

I am having the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713492/box-shadow-being-cut-off), but I need to have `overflow-x` set to `scroll` or else the entire document will be wider than the screen.  Theoretically, setting `overflow-y` to `visible` *should* keep the box shadow visible, but it still cuts it off.  This can be seen with the code below.

```css
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like for the drop shadow to be fully visible outside of the parent div, is this possible at all?

Comment: Nope. You set `overflow` to anything but `visible`, everything stays in, including shadows (in the night)...

Answer (score 5):

Box shadow is cutting off because there supposed to be a scrollbar that you are just hiding.

[image]

**Simple solutoin**

Set a bottom padding to **.scroll** container.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but due to the set up of this site, it would be difficult to do that, I was hoping for another way.

Comment: But why do you use **overflow-x: scroll** since you are hiding it?

Comment: In the actual project, there will be more boxes and has to be scrollable.  If I leave it at `visible` then when the user scrolls, the entire document will scroll and everything below it will be moved.  If I leave it at `hidden` then the other boxes in this row will be hidden as well.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract padding from margin:

```
#container {
  margin: -100px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a padding to the #container so it always shows the shadow, BUT the horizontal shadows will be cut.

```css
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```